# Prove that rational coefficients $\implies$ rational root

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, rational-numbers

Let $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a polynomial such that there exists only one $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(r)=0.$ If $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q},$ show that $r\in\mathbb{Q}.$

I do not know how to approach this question. In a hint, we were asked to examine the roots of $p'$ as well. Well, if $r$ is the only real root of a quartic polynomial, it must occur with multiplicity $2$ or $4.$ If it occurs with multiplicity $4,$ then, $p'''(r)=24r+6a=0.$ This gives $r=\frac{-a}{4},$ which is rational. How to deal with the multiplicity being $2$ case?

PS: This was a question on an entrance exam that ended $4$ hours ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028773/fourth-degree-polynomial-with-rational-coefficients-and-a-real-root?rq=1

Comment: @Lelouch, it ought to, but I do not fully understand the solution. Where did $\gcd$ of polynomials come from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor

Comment: @Lelouch, okay, I think I understand the answer now. Thanks.