# Prove: If a monic quartic with rational coefficients has one real root, then the root is rational

Tags: polynomials

> The polynomial
> $p(x)=x^4+a x^3+b x^2+c x+d$ has exactly one real number $r$ such that $p(r)=0$. Show that if $a, b, c, d$ are rational, $r$ is also rational.

---

As it's a 4 degree polynomial with only one real root $r$, we know it's a double root. Hence $p(x)= (x-r)^2 q_1(x)$. Now $p'(x)$ also has $r$ as root. Hence $p'(x)= 2(x-r) q_2(x)$. Here $q_2(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial. Now I'm stuck here, how do I proceed

Comment: The same question [Prove that rational coefficients $\implies$ rational root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694415/prove-that-rational-coefficients-implies-rational-root) was posted a few hours earlier. That's why it helps to look around before posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The possibilities are either (i) $r$ is a double root and other two complex roots are of multiplicity one, or (ii) $r$ is of multiplicity four. In the latter case, $p(x)=(x-r)^4$ and $r=-a/4$ is rational. In the former case, the GCD $d(x)=(p(x),p'(x))$ is proportional to $x-r$ and can be computed inside $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Euclid's algorithm. So $r$ is a root of a rational polynomial of degree one, hence rational.

Comment: "So r
 is a root of a rational polynomial of degree one" - Why degree 1 please? Also, OP stated that only 1 real root exists.

Comment: @NoChance In case (i), $r$ is a root of both $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$, so it is a root of the GCD, which is degree one. I don't get why you're reminding us OP stated only one real root exists; we know.

Comment: GCD is of degree one since $(p,p')$ detects exactly multiple roots. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $p(x) = (x-r)^2q(x)$, where $q(x)$ does not have real roots. Let's look at minimal polynomial of $r$, denote it as $m(x)$. Note that degree of $m(x)$ not more than $3$, because $r$ is the root of $p'(x).$ If it has degree $1$ then $r$ is rational. It can't have degree $2$ because $m(x)|p(x)$ and in this case $m(x)$ has two real roots.
Then we get that $m(x) = \frac{p'(x)}{4}.$ But it is easy to check that $p(x) \neq p'(x) q(x)$ if $p(x) \neq (x-r)^4$. (Each root of $p'(x)$ must be the root of $p(x)$ with larger multiplicity.)

Comment: how do we know that $m(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$?

Comment: By the definition I guess  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory), maybe I don't understand some problem?

Comment: Perhaps $p(x)\in\Bbb Q[x],\, p(r)=0\Rightarrow r\in \bar{\Bbb Q}\Rightarrow m\in\Bbb Q[x]$

Comment: Yes, this proves the existance of minimal polynomial, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $p(x)$ must have $r$ as a repeated root. Let's consider the factorization of $p$ over the rational numbers, and let $p_1$ be the irreducible factor of $p$ having $r$ as a root. Since $r$ is a repeated root of $p$, the factor $p_1$ must likewise occur multiple times in the factorization of $p$. Also the degree of $p_1$ is obviously at most $2$. So over the rationals we have one of the following three situations: (i) $p=p_1^4$ with $p_1$ of degree $1$; (ii) $p=p_1^2p_2$ with $p_1$ of degree $1$ and $p_2$ irreducible of degree $2$ (and with non-real roots); or (iii) $p=p_1^2$ with $p_1$ irreducible of degree $2$.

If $p_1$ has degree $1$ then $r$ is obviously rational, so we may assume it has degree $2$. But if a polynomial of degree $2$ with rational coefficients has precisely one real root, then that root must be rational (because the discriminant must then be zero). But this means that $p_1$ was not irreducible, which is a contradiction, showing that case (iii) can't occur in the first place.